# Differential equations with infinite-dimensional Lie groups

Tags: lie-groups, differential-equations, symmetry

I am no expert in solving DEs by symmetry methods, but from pure interest - is it possible for a differential equation to have an infinite-dimesional Lie group as a symmetry group?

Comment: This is answered in the review that Igor Rivin suggested in the answer to this past question of yours https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282450/how-to-find-the-symmetry-group-of-a-differential-equation . See the discussion after Theorem 4. It also appears that sections 6 and 7 discuss several explicit examples.

Comment: The symmetry group of any linear partial differential equation (that is not an ODE) is infinite dimensional, so the answer is 'yes'.